# How to build native RXTX library for Ubuntu12.04/14.04?

Tags: make, c

Can someone give me a tip on how to build the native rxtx library on Ubuntu 12.04/14.04? We need to run on 12.04 but i develop on 14.04.

I grabbed the source files from here:
http://rxtx.qbang.org/pub/rxtx/rxtx-2.1-7r2.zip

All the make files appear to be for windows.
Here are the files i'm looking at:

```
acinclude.m4  COPYING                Makefile.msvc
aclocal.m4    CVS                    missing
AUTHORS       debian                 mkinstalldirs
autogen.sh    INSTALL                PORTING
BeOS          install-japanese.html  README
buildtest     install-sh             README.IPAQ
buildwin32    ltconfig               README.SCO
ChangeLog     ltmain.sh              RMISecurityManager.html
CNI           MacOSX                 rxtx.spec
config.guess  MACOSX_IDE             SerialPortInstructions.txt
config.h.in   Makefile.am            src
config.sub    Makefile.in            stamp-h.in
configure     Makefile.lcc           TODO
configure.in  Makefile.macosx        WinCE
contrib       Makefile.mingw32
```

Basically we want to see if we can avoid the RTS and DTR from being asserted when we connect to the serial port and we suspect it is done in native code.

Comment: And the README says ... and you tried .... and the error message was ....

Comment: Readme does not have anything helpful. I think i got it though but it was pure chance. I'll add an answer although i'm not sure it is the correct one. There might be more i have to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have the solution but i'm not sure if its the right way of doing it. I tried this:

```
.configure
make
```

and it produced this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  3 james james   4096 Sep 11 13:51 x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
-rw-rw-r--  1 james james  59328 Sep 11 13:51 RXTXcomm.jar
drwxrwxr-x  3 james james   4096 Sep 11 13:51 gnu
-rw-rw-r--  1 james james  38973 Sep 11 13:51 config.log
-rw-rw-r--  1 james james     23 Sep 11 13:51 stamp-h1
-rw-rw-r--  1 james james   2318 Sep 11 13:51 config.h
-rw-rw-r--  1 james james  22962 Sep 11 13:51 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x  1 james james  39936 Sep 11 13:51 config.status
-rwxrwxr-x  1 james james 206476 Sep 11 13:51 libtool
drwxr-xr-x  3 james james   4096 Sep 11 12:29 debian
```

I think the native libs are here:

```
james@james-Galago:~/Desktop/rxtx-2.1-7-src-r2/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/.libs$ ls -la *.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james  7683 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxI2C-2.1-7.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 james james    19 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxI2C.so -> librxtxI2C-2.1-7.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james  7683 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxParallel-2.1-7.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 james james    24 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxParallel.so -> librxtxParallel-2.1-7.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james  7683 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxRaw-2.1-7.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 james james    19 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxRaw.so -> librxtxRaw-2.1-7.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james  7683 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxRS485-2.1-7.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 james james    21 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxRS485.so -> librxtxRS485-2.1-7.so
-rwxrwxr-x 1 james james 48632 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxSerial-2.1-7.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 james james    22 Sep 11 13:51 librxtxSerial.so -> librxtxSerial-2.1-7.so
```

But what make me uncertain whether these are the libraries to use is they are in the ".libs" directory which usually hidden by default. Why not name the directory these libs are generated in just "libs" without the "." .

Comment: Now you run `sudo make install` https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware

Comment: Should that install it into my current system I'm developing on or create the installation package?

Comment: Install it into the current system